# cannot launch application server using "node server" in Angular 2

Tags: macos, angular

I am unable to launch my Angular 2 app using the node server command in my mac OSX. I am getting the following error :

```
Bharaths-MacBook-Air:<my-app> xyz$ node server
module.js:327
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/xyz/Desktop/<my-app-dir>/Web/<my-  app>/server'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:974:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `server.js` file really in the directory `<my-app>`?
Try using `node server.js` or `node ./server.js`.

Comment: Yes. I tried doing that but still I am unable to start my app. Is there any workaround for me to run my angular2 project as I am completely new to it.

Comment: @bharry29 are you using angular-cli? Webpack? Some kind of angular2 starter pack projects?

Comment: I am using Mean Stack for my angular 2 project

Comment: @bharry29 Mean stack is just a stack of technologies. To run an angular2 app you should compile it somehow. Where did you get the instructions to run `node server` command? Can you share a link?

Comment: I have figured out the issue. My mongodb was not turned on and that is the reason my app was not starting. Thanks.